# Android Studio Geolocalización y coordenadas manuales

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, geolocalización

Buen día,

Realicé una aplicación donde genera el mapa de google con la ubicación del gps del mismo celular, pero resulta que ahora necesito que me realice las marcas pero de unas coordenadas traídas desde otro lado y mostradas en un textview.

[image: aqui tengo la ubicación inicial y final, en los text view, esos son los que debo marcar en el mapa de google.]

aqui tengo la ubicación inicial y final, en los text view, esos son los que debo marcar en el mapa de google.
Actualmente lo tengo funcionando pero como les comenté con el gps del mismo dispositivo y este es el codigo.

```
package com.example.jhonfregom.egps;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import locat.devazt.networking.HttpClient;
import locat.devazt.networking.OnHttpRequestComplete;
import locat.devazt.networking.Response;

public class GPSActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    String ubicacion;
    String direccion;
    String ciudad;
    double longitud, latitud;
    TextView txtubicacion;
    Button verMapa;
    Button iniciogps, detenergps, guardargps;
    private Button mLogoutBtn;
    TextView txtubicacion2;
    TextView txtubicacion3;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private RequestQueue mPosicion;
    private RequestQueue mPosicionF;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    Localizacion local;
    static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);

        mLogoutBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        iniciogps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inicio);
        detenergps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.detener);
        guardargps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.guardar);
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        txtubicacion2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtubicacion2);
        txtubicacion3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtubicacion3);

        mPosicion = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        mPosicionF = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


        guardargps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                guardarcoord();
            }
        });

        iniciogps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                jsonParse();
            }
        });


        detenergps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                jsonParseF();
            }
        });

        mLogoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(GPSActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });



        txtubicacion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtubicacion);
        verMapa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verMapa);
        verMapa.setOnClickListener(this);
        lanzarLocalizacion();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.


            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(GPSActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

            return;
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) local);

        txtubicacion.setText("Ubicacion agregada");

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(GPSActivity.this,
                            "permission was granted, :)",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    lanzarLocalizacion();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(GPSActivity.this,
                            "permission denied, ...:(",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

    public void setLocation(Location loc) {
        if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
            this.latitud = loc.getLatitude();
            longitud = loc.getLongitude();

            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> direcciones = geocoder.getFromLocation(this.latitud, longitud, 1);

                if (!direcciones.isEmpty()) {
                    Address dir = direcciones.get(0);
                    direccion = dir.getAddressLine(0) + " Ciudad " + dir.getLocality();
                    ciudad = dir.getLocality();
                    txtubicacion.setText(direccion);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public String getUbicacion() {
        return ubicacion;
    }

    public void setUbicacion(String ubicacion) {
        this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
    }


    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    //    i.putExtra("longitud", String.valueOf(longitud));
        i.putExtra("latitud", String.valueOf(this.latitud));
        i.putExtra("ciudad", ciudad);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void lanzarLocalizacion() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(this.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        local = new Localizacion();
        local.setGps(this);
    }




    private void jsonParse() {
      //   String url = "http://192.168.43.109/gpio/1";
       // String url = "http://192.168.0.17/gpio/1";
        String url = "http://api.myjson.com/bins/p498q";


        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("coordenadas");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject coordi = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String latitud = coordi.getString("latitud");
                                String longitud = coordi.getString("longitud");
                                txtubicacion2.append(latitud + "," +longitud +" ");

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mPosicion.add(request);
    }

    private void jsonParseF() {
        //  String url = "http://192.168.43.109/gpio/1";
     //   String  url= "https://api.myjson.com/bins/ib6pm";
     //   String url = "http://192.168.0.17/gpio/1";
        String url = "http://api.myjson.com/bins/p498q";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("coordenadas");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject coordf = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String latitud = coordf.getString("latitud");
                                String longitud = coordf.getString("longitud");
                                txtubicacion3.append(latitud + "," +longitud +" ");

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mPosicionF.add(request);
    }

}
```

Y el fragment del mapa es el siguiente

```js
package com.example.jhonfregom.egps;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
        double latitud=0, longitud=0;
        String direccion;
        String ciudad;
        String ciudadn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        try{

        latitud = Double.parseDouble(extras.getString("latitud"));
        longitud = Double.parseDouble(extras.getString("longitud"));
        ciudad = extras.getString("ciudad");

        }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        }


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng miubiaacion = new LatLng(latitud,longitud);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(miubiaacion).title(ciudad).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(miubiaacion,17));





        }

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Nueva ubicacion",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> direcciones = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);

        if (!direcciones.isEmpty()) {
        Address dir = direcciones.get(0);
        direccion = dir.getAddressLine(0) + " Ciudad " + dir.getLocality();
        ciudadn = dir.getLocality();


        TextView txtubicacion = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.txtubicacionmap);

        txtubicacion.setText(direccion);
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true).title(ciudadn).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

        }



        }
```

Como les dije así me funciona perfecto el gps del mismo dispositivo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es añadir los puntos que te pasar a los textbox tienes que hacer exactamente lo mismo que has hecho con la ubicacion obtenida por gps, simplemente crea otros 2 marker y ya lo tienes